Stuck reading "Optimal Biweighted Binary Trees and the Complexity of Maintaining Partial Sums"
I am reading the paper titled "Optimal Biweighted Binary Trees and the Complexity of Maintaining Partial Sums", and I am stuck on theorem 2.1, I believe it is wrong, the proof has a wrong direction and therefore the construction does not work.
In particular, on Page 5 of this copy:
https://sci-hub.st/https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539795291598
There is a paragraph starting with:
Now every set $ R_j $ ...
From my understanding, the goal of this paragraph is to establish the existence of $ \overline{R}^l $ as a UR system, and we wish to maintain that
$$ |U_i \cap R_j| = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } i \le j \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases} $$
From my understanding, in order for that to work, we need the fact $ x_j \notin U_i $ for all $i \le j $, but the paper proved that $ x_j \notin U_h $ for all $ h > j $, which doesn't really help?
To be concrete, here is an example showing the construction does not work.
Let's say I have an UR system as such:



Leaf
U
R




1
{A,B,D}
{D}


2
{E,A}
{E,B}


3
{C}
{C,A}



Here are the u-extent values for variables:



Variable
u-extent




A
2


B
1


C
3


D
1


E
2



Here are the u-extent values for the R subsets



R
u-extent




1
1


2
1


3
1



So we get $ k = 1 $.
Now we can simply pick $ x_j \in R $ to construct a UR system for the right hand side.



Leaf
U
R - x_j




2
{E,A}
{B}


3
{C}
{A}



But wait, this isn't a valid UR system anymore ...
Something is wrong here, help!
For those who read Chinese, here is a longer version of the reading notes:
https://awesome-grease-f49.notion.site/Optimal-Biweighted-Binary-Trees-and-the-Complexity-of-Maintaining-Partial-Sums-6ee94db9f91747e8b042938172ffca3d

In your example, the u-extent of R3  is 2.


From my understanding, in order for that to work, we need the fact $x_j\not\in U_i$ for all $i\le j$, but the paper proved that $x_j\not\in U_h$ for all $h>j$, which doesn't really help?

In that paragraph they say that $x_j \not\in U_h$ for all $h > k$. That gives us the following, for $i > k$
$$U_i \cap (R_j - \{x_j\}) = U_i \cap R_j$$ which is what we need to preserve condition 1.1 for $U^r_i = U_{k+i}$ and $R^r_j = R_{k+j} - \{x_{k+j}\}$ (for $1 \le i \le N-k$).
Your counterexample is not valid because the u-extent of $R_3$ should be $2$.
